# Unable to get error stack trace or error log while using php-fpm + nginx on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, php, nginx, php-fpm

I am using php-fpm 5.5.9 along with nginx 1.4.6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I have installed them using apt-get package manager. I am unable to get a stack trace of the error that my index.php script encounters in error log as well as on the browser. I searched and implemented a couple of solutions from stackoverflow and other articles but none of them worked for me. Here is my nginx conf along with my php-fpm conf file. Please help me out if I am  doing any silly mistake.

**Nginx Configuration:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        # With php5-fpm:
                #try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        proxy_connect_timeout  600;
        proxy_send_timeout  600s;
        proxy_read_timeout  600s;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
```

**PHP-FPM Configuration:**

```
error_log = /tmp/php5-fpm.log
```

**PHP-FPM pool Configuration:**

```
catch_workers_output = yes 
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/$pool.log.slow
listen = 127.0.0.1:7777

php_flag[display_errors] = On 
php_admin_value[error_log] = /tmp/fpm-php.www.log 
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = On
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put in your site's configuration inside the server directive the following:

```
access_log  /var/log/nginx/your_site.log;

error_log   /var/log/nginx/your_site.log;
```

replace the `your_site.log` with the name of your virtualhost - domain name.

**Full example:**

**php-fpm**

**`/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf`**

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php5-fpm.log
include=/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
```

**`/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d`**

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 6
```

**Virtual host**

```js
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

    root /srv/www/mysite;
    index index.php;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/mysite_error.log;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
              root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        }



        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9$
        location ~ \.php$ {
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                 }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
        access_log off;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I already have nginx access log and error log setup correctly in my server directive but it does not output php-fpm error log.

Comment: All my error paths are pointing to /tmp folder so access should not be an issue.

Comment: @TojoChacko added the php-fpm configuration. Both configurations are from a live wordpress site with working logging facilities, for nginx inside the `/var/log/nginx/mysite_...` and for php-fpm in `/var/log/php-fpm.log`

Comment: tried your conf file but still php-fpm does not log errors :(

Comment: @TojoChacko nginx error log should be in notice level.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the execution errors of a script, that's configured on `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`.

If you want errors on a log file, edit `php.ini` :

```
display_errors  = off 
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
error_log = /path/to/some/file.log
```

If you want them on the browser, edit `php.ini` :

```
display_errors  = on
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

or, adding it on top of the script :

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT );
```

I don't know a way to log the stack trace directly on the logfile , but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8369329/1810128) there's a way that you can implement defining your own error handler.